# How can I unlink multiple images at once?

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

I have this code which will delete images with the category name from my database and but it only unlink one image from my images folder but I need it to unlink multiple images at once can anyone help here is an example of my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $delete_id = $_GET['delete'];

    $sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE category = '$delete_id'";

    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $image = $row['image'];

        $location_full_image = "../images/$image";

        $location_thumb_image = "../images/thumbnails/$image";

        @unlink($location_full_image); 

        @unlink($location_thumb_image); 

        $sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE category = '$delete_id'";

        $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());

    } 

}
```

Comment: Try to avoid including unrelated code like the MySQL calls, since they aren't related to the issue of unlinking multiple files.

Comment: I would rather have those extra lines of code than not enough, as far too many people on SO don't give enough context.

Comment: user3152355: You'd probably have better luck diagnosing this issue if you weren't using the `@` operator to suppress the error messages.

Comment: I am not getting any errors it works fine it deletes all image names from the database but then it only unlinks one image from the folder. So say I have three images in the folder, all three image names are deleted from the database but only one of the three images are unlinked.

Comment: try `print_r(error_get_last());` after unlink (and remove the `@` operator). More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333027/how-to-get-error-result-of-unlink

Answer (score 2):

try below code and make sure you are fetching right column from database which contains image name.

```
 if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

$delete_id = $_GET['delete'];

$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE category = '$delete_id'";

$query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $image = $row['image'];

    @unlink('../images/'.$image); 

    @unlink('../images/thumbnails/'.$image); 

    $sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE category = '$delete_id'";

    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());

} 

}
```

Comment: There are sql injection holes in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $image = $row['img'];


   @unlink("images/".$image);
}
```